# Циклический выбор блока и изменение цвета

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/23hu02pw/

Задача 
Создайте страницу. Разместите на 5странице элементов div и кнопку . Создайте CSS файл,определите в файле правила, которые зададут всем дивам следующее – высота оформление иширина 100 px, float = left и зеленый цвет фона.Создайте сценарий, который будет рабатывать об нажатие по кнопке и менять цвет одногодивов на красный. Смена цвета должна происходить , при циклически первом нажатии первыйdiv становиться красный остальные остаются зелеными, при – втором все div нажатиистановятся зелеными, а второй красный и т.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/23hu02pw/1/

[[@msim](/users/20441/msim)](/users/20441/msim), на будущее - постарайтесь внятно описывать задачу, при этом уточнив, что конкретно вы сделали и где возникли затруднения.